# Schedule a Job at specific time of the day

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager, job-scheduling

### Backgroud

I am using `AlarmManager` and `JobScheduler`(=> API 21) to generate Notification at 11 am in the morning.

### Issue

Suppose my device is turned off at 11 am. So **Alarm will not go off and Notification is not generated** for **today**. Now, when it will reboot. the alarm is set again for **11 am of next day** using  `BroadCastReceiver` on `action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

I have explored Job Scheduler a bit and `setPeriodic(ms)` function is used to set a periodic job but does not allow to schedule a job at specific time.
*(Google -> define schedule -> arrange or plan (an event) **to take place at a particular time.**).*

Any pointer to workarounds to this use case. I would prefer native solution, though.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242338/847235

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android start running JobScheduler at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301351/android-start-running-jobscheduler-at-specific-time)