# How to run a Job at a specific time every day?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am new on using job libraries as Job Scheduler. I have seen a lot of documentation and none of them responds to my question, is it possible to schedule a job for 9PM (for example) and that same job runs everyday at 9PM(the hour of the initial job). What I have seen are people setting a periodic time but I dont know if the periodic starts when the job runs for the first time our if I could specify an hour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android schedule task to execute at specific time daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344220/job-scheduler-not-running-on-android-n)

Comment: If you can see the post, he uses Alarm Manager. I want to know about Job Scheduler ;)

Comment: @jose check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301351/android-start-running-jobscheduler-at-specific-time

Comment: use alarm manager

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to set exact, periodic job? If yes, it is not possible. Every periodic job is inexact. This mean that job will be executed at any time in a window of flex length at the end of the period. And the requirement is that the flex time is at least 5% of the period.

Take a look at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic(long,%20long)